# Fruit bowl task

Tags: python

You have a bowl on your counter with **an even number** of pieces of fruit in it. Half of them are bananas, and the other half are apples. *You need 3 apples to make a pie*.

Task
Your task is to evaluate the total number of pies that you can make with the apples that are in your bowl given to total amount of fruit in the bowl.

Ihis task in this way. Is there a better solution than this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CGfQ.png)

```
fruit = int(input())
pie = 0
apple = int(fruit /2)


while apple >= 3:
    apple -= 3
    pie += 1
print(pie)
```

Comment: If you had 300 apples, how many pies can you make? Did you need to subtract 3 repeatedly in order to get the answer or was there a simpler way?

Comment: There's a mathematical operation for making "repeatedly removing a fixed value" quicker: it's called... integer division! In Python, it's written as `//`

Comment: What do you mean by *"Ihis task in this way"*? Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77061633/edit) it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the *while* statement with a floored division.

```
pie = floor(apple / 3)
print(pie)
```

To use floor, you need to import the math library.
It is similar to round, but it always rounds down and essentially truncates by 0 decimal points.

If you don't want to use floor, a cleaner syntax is

```
pie = apple // 3
print(pie)
```

Comment: What is "[dp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DP#Science,_technology,_and_mathematics)"? Decimal point? [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)?

Comment: decimal point, that is what it is called in british education sorry if this doesn't translate